# How to use Huggingface Transformers with PrimeQA model?

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, nlp-question-answering

Here is the model https://huggingface.co/PrimeQA/t5-base-table-question-generator

Hugging face says that I should use the following code to use the model in transformers:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("PrimeQA/t5-base-table-question-generator")

model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("PrimeQA/t5-base-table-question-generator")
```

It also provides a link to this documentation in the model https://github.com/primeqa/primeqa/blob/main/notebooks/qg/tableqg_inference.ipynb

It has the following code:

```
from primeqa.qg.models.qg_model import QGModel
from tabulate import tabulate # only used to visualize table



model_name = 'PrimeQA/t5-base-table-question-generator'
table_qg_model = QGModel(model_name, modality='table')

table_list = [
    {"header": ["Player", "No.", "Nationality", "Position", "Years in Toronto", "School Team"],
      "rows": [
            ["Antonio Lang", 21, "United States", "Guard-Forward", "1999-2000", "Duke"],
            ["Voshon Lenard", 2, "United States", "Guard", "2002-03", "Minnesota"],
            ["Martin Lewis", 32, "United States", "Guard-Forward", "1996-97", "Butler CC (KS)"],
            ["Brad Lohaus", 33, "United States", "Forward-Center", "1996", "Iowa"],
            ["Art Long", 42, "United States", "Forward-Center", "2002-03", "Cincinnati"]
        ]
    }
]
# [optional] include an id_list aligned with table_list
id_list = ["abcID123"]

print(tabulate(table_list[0]['rows'], headers=table_list[0]['header'], tablefmt='grid'))



table_qg_model.generate_questions(table_list, 
                                    num_questions_per_instance = 5,
                                    agg_prob = [1.,0,0,0,0,0],
                                    num_where_prob = [0,1.,0,0,0],
                                    ineq_prob = 0.0,
                                    id_list=id_list
                                )
```

How do I combine these two snippets? I did the following but I get errors:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("PrimeQA/t5-base-table-question-generator")

model_name = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("PrimeQA/t5-base-table-question-generator")

table_list = [
    {"header": ["Player", "No.", "Nationality", "Position", "Years in Toronto", "School Team"],
      "rows": [
            ["Antonio Lang", 21, "United States", "Guard-Forward", "1999-2000", "Duke"],
            ["Voshon Lenard", 2, "United States", "Guard", "2002-03", "Minnesota"],
            ["Martin Lewis", 32, "United States", "Guard-Forward", "1996-97", "Butler CC (KS)"],
            ["Brad Lohaus", 33, "United States", "Forward-Center", "1996", "Iowa"],
            ["Art Long", 42, "United States", "Forward-Center", "2002-03", "Cincinnati"]
        ]
    }
]

model_name.generate_questions(table_list, 
                                    num_questions_per_instance = 5,
                                    agg_prob = [1.,0,0,0,0,0],
                                    num_where_prob = [0,1.,0,0,0],
                                    ineq_prob = 0.0
                                )
```

It gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'T5ForConditionalGeneration' object has no attribute 'generate_questions'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load `PrimeQA/t5-base-table-question-generator` model using the Huggingface transformers library directly. However you cannot call the function `generate_questions`. This is because the function `generate_questions` is defined in the class [QGModel](https://github.com/primeqa/primeqa/blob/main/primeqa/qg/models/qg_model.py#L27). `QGModel` is a wrapper around the Huggingface `AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM` class and provides additional functionalities like reduce hallucinations etc. These functions are not defined in the `AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM` class.

So, you could load the model using `AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM` and perform generation using `model.generate()`. However, you cannot call the function `generate_questions()` or `prune_hallucinations()` as they are defined in the `QGModel` class.